# Hum.exe - programs not launching on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, malware-removal

After a infection by what seems to be a malware / trojan, a windows 7 doesn't start its executables but rather opens the "select a program for this extension" list box, with the extension being .exe

Any way to repair this? I'm thinking about poking in the registry but i would like to know if somebody already encountered that before rushing in the system's bowels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. [Here](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/exefile.htm) is a link to the patch/fix. Just download and run.
Here is the manual method:

> Click Start, Run and type `command`
>   Type the following commands one by one:
>       `cd\windows`
>       `regedit`
>
> If Registry Editor opens successfully, then navigate to the following key:
>   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT \ exefile \ shell \ open \ command`
>   Double-click the (Default) value in the right pane
>   Delete the current value data, and then type:
>   `"%1" %*`
>   (ie., quote-percent-one-quote-space-percent-asterisk.)
>   Navigate to: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe`
>   In the right-pane, set `(default)` to `exefile`
>   Exit the Registry Editor.

Comment: You should include a description of how to fix it manually in case the link goes dead.

Comment: Done, sorry for not posting it origonally.