# I keep having to System Restore

Tags: windows, windows-registry, malware, system-restore

Sorry the question title isn't very helpful.

Anyway, every so often (week or so, irregular intervals) my computer just stops working properly. I get a program claiming to be something like "Win7 Security 2012". It reads all of my files and marks random ones with random "virus" warnings. It hooks into `.exe` binaries and claims that they are keyloggers and trojans and should be deleted. If I happen to have a browser already open, it blocks all HTTP requests and claims that the site I'm trying to access contain malware.

The program is located in %LOCALAPPDATA% and has what appears to be three random letters (it changes each time and sometimes there's two of them) followed by `.exe`. If I kill it in Task Manager (which I can only get to via Ctrl+Alt+Delete => Start Task Manager) it just comes back again. If I delete the file, I can no longer run `.exe`s because it asks me what program to open them with (which is of course an infinite loop).

The only way I can fix this is to run System Restore. I'm assuming that it's something in the registry that's being restored.

Can someone please tell me how to make `.exe`s run on their own again, and optionally find out where these `.exe`s are coming from and how to block them in future? Bonus points if you can tell me if it's possible (and if so how) to "protect" the `.exe` entry in the registry to stop it happening again.

Comment: have you tried the usual proper AV stuff like malwarebytes or combofix? There's a [question/community wiki](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) on it. Failing which, back up, and nuking it would be a good idea, since what you have *is* obviously a rather pesky persisitant virus

Comment: My answer to http://superuser.com/questions/314830/hum-exe-programs-not-launching-on-windows-7/314846#314846 will get .exe running again. I think you have a corrupted backup (the virus is in it)

Comment: Yes, I have tried AV, antimalware, rootkit finder, everything I could think of. I could nuke the computer (I have full backup with JungleDisk) but I would rather not if an alternative is available because then I'd have to get all of my programs installed again.

Comment: @Kolink, does the patch allow you to run .exe s again?

Comment: I imagine it would. Obviously I can't test it until I get the problem again, but I'm pretty sure that would fix it.

Comment: If you're running your A/V scans in safe mode *and* in normal (you should be) and you're still seeing an infection, you are either re-infecting the OS or the virus has infected the boot sector of your OS. You could be reinfecting the OS with a USB/thumb drive or another program you're running after install. I agree with above that your restore image could be infected as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen it before. If you can pull out the hard drive and put it into another computer, delete the files in question from your `%APPDATA%\Local` folder, which are probably hidden. Otherwise, start in Safe Mode with Networking. Download the .EXE fix (directions to create it from Microsoft are [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950505)). Once you apply that fix, you can run applications. Connect to the internet and download a program such as [Malwarebytes Antimalware](http://www.ninite.com/malwarebytes/ninite.exe) and run a scan (NOTE: Link is from Ninite to get the install right away). Do a full system scan, then you can restart your computer in normal mode

Comment: FYI I have never downloaded a single piece of pirated software. As a developer myself I am strongly against such practices and would appreciate it if you didn't accuse me of them.

Comment: @Kolink Appologies, removed the comment

Comment: Answer accepted, because it just happened again (I wasn't even doing anything at the time, just idling) and this answer helped a lot. btw, can anyone tell me how to track the source of an exe? Windows can ("Downloaded form the Internet" / "CD-DVD" / "Hard drive on local machine" etc) so can I?

Comment: That would be another question, but it's basically from the ADS (Alternate Data Stream). I don't know how much info it stores though